# How to make a target in make that is itself named 'makefile'?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Summary**: I'm dealing with a make script that generates (and optionally 'makes') a makefile.  Historically it used a `make make` "phony target" to do so.  I want to change this to `make makefile` because it seems more coherent and representative of what's going on.  But when I change it and switch to the .FORCE idiom so it will be generated dependent on an artificial phony target, it seems the makefile is created 4 extra times for a reason I do not understand.

**Details:** The way the script works is that you can write either:

```
make -f makefile.boot
```

or:

```
make -f makefile.boot make
```

In the first case, it assumes you want to use the rules in `makefile.boot` to generate a platform-specific `makefile`, and then run `make` on that file.  In the second case it assumes you only want to create the makefile but not execute it.

Here is a stripped down version of **makefile.boot** in `make make` terms that works:

```
top: make
    $(MAKE)

make:
    @echo "Pretending to generate makefile..."
    cp makefile.fake makefile
```

The makefile we "generate" wants to be a *superset* of makefile.boot.  It wants to be able to do the `make make` generation process as well, but its `top` target is an actual build.  So **makefile.fake** contains

```
top: product

make:
    @echo "Pretending to generate makefile..."
    cp makefile.fake makefile

product:
    @echo "Pretending to make build product..."
    echo "Build Product" >> product
```

It works, but I had a thought:

> "make make" is confusing to read, and it would be clearer if it was "make makefile" instead

An immediate problem with that is when you have a real target instead of a phony one, then if the file exists and has no dependencies it won't get rebuilt.  I wanted this makefile to be created every time you did `make makefile` or `make -f makefile.boot makefile`.  So I used the .FORCE idiom to *depend* on a phony target.  Updated **makefile.boot**:

```
.FORCE

top: makefile
    $(MAKE)

makefile: .FORCE
    @echo "Pretending to generate makefile..."
    cp makefile.fake makefile
```

And an updated **makefile.fake**:

```
.FORCE:

top: product

makefile: .FORCE
    @echo "Pretending to generate makefile..."
    cp makefile.fake makefile

product:
    @echo "Pretending to make build product..."
    echo "Build Product" >> product
```

Which seems all well and good, but *it now runs the makefile generation five times*:

```
/test$ make -f makefile.boot
Pretending to generate makefile...
cp makefile.fake makefile
make
make[1]: Entering directory '/test'
Pretending to generate makefile...
cp makefile.fake makefile
Pretending to generate makefile...
cp makefile.fake makefile
Pretending to generate makefile...
cp makefile.fake makefile
Pretending to generate makefile...
cp makefile.fake makefile
Pretending to make build product...
echo "Build Product" >> product
make[1]: Leaving directory '/test'
```

The first one I want, and seems like the only one I asked for.  Where are all the other calls coming from?  What's triggering the four additional requests for `makefile`?  Or in the absence of understanding, is there an alternative way of achieving my intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do recall that `makefile` is a magic target in many `make` implementations, [including GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles).

If the target `makefile` exists, then `make` will remake the makefile *before doing anything else*, and when it's finished it'll restart processing with the new makefile.  That means that your `makefile` target may be run even if you don't ask for it.

Since the default action when you do `make -f makefile.boot` is to run `make`, then that's at least *two* potential runs of the `makefile` target's actions right there, before it's even looked at the `product` target.  I can't quite make this add up to five runs, but I'd lay money that it's this special behaviour that's causing the unexpected repeats.

Comment: I wouldn't recall it because I never really got very into GNU/unix makefile lore!!  But I figured there must be something special about `makefile`, thanks for the pointer.  Guess I can contemplate whether I want to have `makefile.boot` offer `makefile` (since that's all it does) and then either get rid of the generated makefile being able to do a regeneration (and have you use makefile.boot again) or accept that it uses `make` instead.